# Tabulator: autoColumnsDefinitions using custom cell formatter and dynamically defined fields?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have an ajax Tabulator in which I'd like to use a custom cell formatter on columns which are dynamically (but similarly) defined.

Let's say I have a dataset of People with "Event" columns, where the ajax response can contain up to 50 Event fields, named Event1,Event2...Event50.
I could manually repeat the definitions using the [Column Definition Array or Field Name Lookup Object approaches](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/columns#autocolumns), like:

```
    autoColumnsDefinitions:{
        PersonID: { title:"ID #", align:"right"},
        Event1: {formatter: eventFormatter},
        Event2: {formatter: eventFormatter},
        ...[variable # of Event cols here]...
    },
```

...

```
   function eventFormatter(cell){
      // format event here
   }
```

---

However, using a callback seems more appropriate. When I try something like this, my eventFormatter is never invoked, and no errors or warnings are raised.

```
    autoColumnsDefinitions:function(definitions){
        definitions.forEach((column) => {
            if(column.field.match(/Event/)) {
                column = {
                    formatter:eventFormatter
                }
            }
```

Is it possible to apply a custom cell formatter to fields that are not explicitly named prior to data loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your must update 'column' with `formatter` as

```
autoColumnsDefinitions: function (definitions) {
  return definitions.map((column) => {
    if (column.field.match(/(name|title)/)) {
      column.formatter = titleFormatter;
    }
    return column;
  });
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doublehrajput/s9g4Lr6y/2/)